# Expression pattern of type 'Double' cannot match values of type '[Double]'?

Tags: swift, syntax

```
if gpa[12] < gpa[1] {
    print(gpa[12])
} else { 
    switch gpa {
    case gpa[1]:
        print(gpa)
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to fix or what this may mean? I am on Xcode 9
What I am doing is trying to have values of GPA switched. I am using cases to switch out. Sorry, I'm new and it's hard for me to explain what I mean.

Comment: You are comparing Double type to the Array of Type double.

Comment: What do you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: See the answer of Simon McLoughlin. He is right...

Answer (score 0):

```
switch gpa
```

here `gpa` is an array of doubles, `[Double]`

```
case gpa[1]:
```

here the case is using a single `Double` value.

What the error message is telling you is that you can not ask a switch to compare a `Double` value ( gpa[1] ) to the entire array of gpa's ( gpa ) because they are different types.